How to calculate magnetic force produced by electromagnet through a medium at a distance
I am attempting to make a chessboard that has a strong electromagnet beneath the board, so that a piece with imbedded metal or magnet can move above the board. The image below is for reference only and is not to scale.
The variables I can change are board thickness, board material and the choice of electromagnet. However, I do not know how to do the correct calculations to solve this scenario and make sure that my chess pieces will have enough force to overcome the friction of the table?

